# Animate an image with jQuery

Tags: animation, jquery-animate, graphic

So here's a strange one. I am working on a cunstruction page for a website I'm about to start. It's a childrens educational website and I thought it would be cool if the cartoon monkey (the companies brand) rolls along the page, from left to right and leaves a message  saying "coming soon..." either above or underneath where the monkey rolls.

I have the monkey in a png format and I was wondering if there was a jQuery method that would make it firstly rotate, and move left to right at the same time as the page has loaded?

Thoughts and how-tos will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

For rotation use jQuery+css:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 1):

This might help?

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Using the above to help with the rotation, sliding left and right would be just a matter of changing the horizontal positioning.